# MonoTouch - foreach vs for loops (performance)

Tags: iphone, foreach, closures, xamarin.ios

Normally I'm well aware that a consideration like this is premature optimization.  Right now I have some event handlers being attached inside a foreach loop.  I am wondering if this style might be prone to leaks or inefficient memory use due to closures being created.  Is there any validity to this thinking?

Answer (score 1):

closures only apply if your event handlers are anonymous methods (including, but not limited to, lambda expressions).  If this is the case, you might have a problem.  But it should be okay as long as you remove these event handlers at the proper time.

Comment: If no anonymous methods are used, is there a significant performance difference when using foreach vs for?

Comment: The only way to know is to profile, but I'm pretty confident in saying there won't be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about something like this:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    item.SomeEvent += delegate {
        // do something
    };
}
```

Then the answer is the performance is not noticeable (in my Monotouch experience anyway) as the compiler simply creates a class with a method the same way the Microsoft C# compiler.

The biggest performance bottlenecks I've encountered in Monotouch have been SQLite related, and parsing DateTimes. Everything else, including complex LINQ statements fly on the 3GS - I'm not sure what magic is performed by the AOT compiler but I would only worry if it creeps up into 0.5 or more seconds to perform the task.